# VB net Transferring DGV1 TO DGV2

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm trying to Transfer DataGridView1 VALUES to another DataGridV 2.. 
that has a Database (MS ACCESS) But this code won't work help please

```
Dim MyConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=..\ItemInssu.accdb")
Dim insertCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tbLItemIssuance(ItemCode, DateIssued, Quantity) VALUES ('" & ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows(ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "','" & ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows(ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "','" & ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows(ItemInssuance.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(2).Value.ToString & "')", MyConnection)
Try
    MyConnection.Open()
    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ItemInssuance.Show()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    MyConnection.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: You just asked this [same question 4 hours ago (though in rougher form)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41806924/1070452).  The Right Thing to do is to carefully read [ask], take the [Tour] and edit your old question with this code (formatted!) and any additional details

Comment: Even in this question you haven't really explained exactly what the issue you are having is or what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: That code appears to have nothing at all to do with the question of "transferring" DGV1 to DGV2

Comment: You already asked this here, dont post dups: [**About Vb.net and Ms Access Transfer DataGridView 1 to Another DataGridView 2 Form**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806924/about-vb-net-and-ms-access-transfer-datagridview-1-to-another-datagridview-2-for)